# AngularJS $broadcast and isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

So I have two directives `splitter` and `pane` that may be used like so:

```
<splitter>
   <pane></pane>
   <pane></pane>
</splitter>
<splitter>
</splitter>
```

I want them all to have isolate or inherited scope. However I also want to be able to `$broadcast` (or equivalent) between them so that if I were to `$broadcast` on one directive's scope, the same event would be triggered on all the nested directives that are listening but not it's parent or siblings (no `$rootScope` here).

How would one go about doing this? My solution must be future friendly as I will be adding more directives in to the mix which also listen for this event.

Comment: You can make a service that both directives load and then share the variables that you want both directives to be able to manipulate

Comment: @LloydBanks True, but at that point, it is really no different from using `$rootScope` to broadcast/receive, which he doesn't want to use.  In other words, if you have multiple splitters, the service won't know which child to route it to.  Just like using `$rootScope` to broadcast, you can't control which listeners get the message.

Comment: @LloydBanks they aren't manipulating shared variables, they are triggering an event. In this particular use-case it is to do with resizing. When I fire a `resize` event I want it to propagate to all children so that they in turn can react to it. `window.onresize` is not enough as the elements can be resized individually of the window and should only affect their children that choose to listen.

Comment: @GeorgeReith A shared service can easily be turned into a pub/sub service, so @LloydBanks is not incorrect here.  The problem is with targeting.  A shared service is just as global as `$rootScope`.  You could use either mechanism to communicate, but you can't properly target.  The only way I know of to do that is to have them all have a shared "communications Id", and then filter the messages based on communication IDs.  It is ugly, but I can't come up with another solution... other than requiring directive controllers OR not using isolated scope, which you also don't want, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

To do inter-directive communication, the best is to use the parent directive controller and expose methods in `this`.

Then you just have to require it in your children directive (`require: '^splitter'`) and the parent controller will be injected as the fourth argument of your `link` function.

For more information, you can see the official documentation about [Creating Directives that Communicate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate).

Comment: Hmmm... that is what I originally said, but @George marked me down, saying that it wasn't a valid answer, so I deleted it.  I still think that this is the best approach.  +1

Comment: @BrianGenisio I didn't mark you down. I was sad you deleted it, although it's not what I'm after (requires too much coupling becomes unmanageable for the sort of scale I'm after) I was glad it was posted. This also fails when I want to nest the same directive within itself as `^splitter` also injects the directives own controller if it matches (the documentation is lacking in that regard).